# RNN Architecture for a Many to Many time series forecasting problem

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to forecast the yield curve (multiple time series) with a RNN/LSTM/GRU model in Keras.

As input I have the 12 interest rate price series (which make up the yield curve) and some more variables like SP500, etc. As an output I would like only a forecast of the 12 interest rates.

I am very new to NN time series forecasting and I was wondering if this is possible in Keras and what kind of things I should be aware of. I also appreciate any tips.

thank you!

Comment: Sounds interesting.  I haven't used Keras so cannot offer specific advice in that direction.  More generically, maybe warm up with a simplified problem, like one or two interest rate series and maybe one other variable?  Better yet, replicate a simple model that is described somewhere, and then modify it incrementally to be more like your target model.

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow documentation offers amazing tutorial to start with.
You can explore the tutorial [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series) to understand the timeseries using `Tensorflow`.

Also, refer to some of the blogs mentioned below and use the method which fits your requirement.

- [Multi-step LSTM time series.](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-lstm-models-for-multi-step-time-series-forecasting-of-household-power-consumption/)
- [Multivariate Time series.](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/)
- [Many to Many LSTM with TimeDistributed](https://machinelearningmastery.com/timedistributed-layer-for-long-short-term-memory-networks-in-python/).